# I have tried to make 2x zoom of an Image in android

Tags: android, zooming

I have tried to 2x zoom a image in android. But haven't find any suitable answer. I have also tried to dot this using achartengine.jar Api, but haven't successful. IS there any option to do this or does the achartengine.jar work for image zooming?

Answer (score 0):

aChartEngine is a charting library and has nothing to do with zooming images.
Have a look at the following page:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html